# TypeScript dynamic import with path variable type

Tags: typescript

I have a directory of TS files, I specify a path to this directory in a config object. I then use `readdirSync` to grab all the files and loop over them, instantiating them, and adding the instance to an object. The below is the inner loop:

```
  const path = join(config.path, file); // file = foo.js
  const className = pascalCase(basename(file, ".js")); // Foo
  type ModuleType = typeof import(path); // uh-oh
  const File = await import(path);
  const Obj = File[className]; // [Function: Foo]
  someObj.handlers[className] = new Obj();
```

I get a TS error when trying to set the `typeof` the import:

> [ts] String literal expected.
>   [ts] 'path' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

Is there anything I can do to tell TS more about the Class I'm importing and instantiating? I know its because I'm using a variable as the `path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating this dynamically at run-time. The types have no meaning at run-time.

If you want design-time intellisense for the object you are constructing at run-time, you will have to write an `interface` to describe it by hand.

If you don't know the shape, then you don't need the type information.

Comment: Thought as much...oh well, need to re-think a few things I think!